# Activity Indicator webView Xcode 5 IOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, android-activity, xcode5

Hi i have a problem with creating a Activity Indicator for my webView, this is the code im using.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView*activityind;
NSTimer *timer; 
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/geekylemon"]]];
[webview addSubview:activityind];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
target:self
selector:@selector(loading)
userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];

}

-(void)loading {  
if (!webview.loading)
    [activityind stopAnimating];
else
    [activityind startAnimating];
} 
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add the activity indicator as a subview of your webview, just position it where you want in the UI in interface builder and connect it to your outlet.

Also make sure the **hidesWhenStopped** property is set to **YES**. You can do this in the **viewDidLoad** method of your controller.

Like this - (*working with your existing code*)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     activityind.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
     [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/geekylemon"]]];
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
          target:self
          selector:@selector(loading)
          userInfo:nil
          repeats:YES];
}
```

Also remember to invalidate the timer when you stop animating the activity indicator.

This tutorial I found on youTube explains very well exactly what you are asking - [iPhone Programming - UIActivityIndicator with a WebView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uSh34kpQ6Y)

Answer (score 4):

i would suggest using the delegate methods of the UIWebView to stop and start your activity indicator.

webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad should be exactly what your looking for.

in view did load set your view controller as the delegate like so:

```
webview.delegate = self;
```

then in your .h file specify that your viewController conforms to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol by changing your .h file to this:

```
@interface ViewController :UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView*activityind;
NSTimer *timer; 
}
@end
```

Then in your .m file use the delegate methods:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [activityind startAnimating];

}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [activityind stopAnimating];
}
```